# Lubuntu Sapphire GPU DVI-I not detected

Tags: lubuntu, display

Hi everyone I have a Sapphire nitro GPU that supports DisplayPort, HDMI, DVI-D and DVI-I and I'm using a DVI-I to VGA adaptor. But my computer  detects the DVI-I port as a DVI-D so its not sending output video to the monitor. It does detect the monitor info but no picture. I've been looking through the internet for like 3 days now and Still nothing has helped so I thought I'd ask here how to fix this?. This is the XrandR output

```
kyle@kyle-pc:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3520 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)`
HDMI-A-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
1680x1050     59.88  
1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
1440x900      74.98    59.90  
1280x960      60.00  
1280x800      60.00  
1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
1024x768      75.03    60.00  
800x600       75.00    60.32  
720x576       50.00  
720x480       60.00    59.94  
640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
720x400       70.08  
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-1 connected 1600x900+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y 
axis) 434mm x 236mm
1600x900      60.00*+
1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
1440x900      60.00  
1280x800      60.00  
1280x720      60.00  
1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
832x624       74.55  
800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
720x400       70.08
```

Also the Monitor does display during BIOS startup but as soon as it boots into the OS it shows with No Signal then sleeps. Btw my monitor only has VGA.
Thx.

Comment: Why is noone concerned or saying anything about this :(

Comment: I dont Care anymore. If no one wants to help thats fine. I've waited long enough and you all don't seem to care.